# delete a user by a customer admin page in Django (not Django Admin page)

Tags: django

I want to make a admin page, and it can manage some user account, I can add some account by this page, delete an account one by one by this page. But I think I got something wrong...?
This is my code:

---

### models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
#here some other fields

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

---

### views.py

```
def deleteuser(request, id):
user = Account.objects.filter(username = id)
user.delete()
return render(request=request,
              template_name='account/profile/profile.html')
```

---

### urls.py

```
path('accounts/delete_account/<id>/', views.deleteuser, name='deleteuser'),
```

---

### profile.html

```
<a href="{% url 'deleteuser' username %}">{% trans "Delete" %}</a>
```

---

### Error

---

```
NoReverseMatch at /profile/
Reverse for 'deleteuser' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/delete_account/(?P<id>[^/]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'deleteuser' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/delete_account/(?P<id>[^/]+)/$']
Exception Location: /Users/likelitchi/.local/share/virtualenvs/student-examination-system-nAzcILXN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
Python Executable:  /Users/likelitchi/.local/share/virtualenvs/student-examination-system-nAzcILXN/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/likelitchi/Documents/GitHub/student-examination-system',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/likelitchi/.local/share/virtualenvs/student-examination-system-nAzcILXN/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 13 Jul 2020 05:43:22 +0000
Error during template rendering
```

I still can find way to solve it... thanks!!

Comment: I think that this line wouldn't compile.`user = Account.objects.get(username=username)`  Where is `username` defined or did you mean `self.username`?

Comment: Oh! yes, thanks for reminding, the first one should be the username in Account, and the second one is the value get from template.

Comment: But, that's still not working...HELP

Comment: Maybe you should post the full trace of the error.

Comment: take a hard look at the error message you are getting. It is telling you what is wrong. Probably something with your urls.py. but this is not my code.

Comment: OH, I see, but how can I get a value from Django Template through url?